# Calling javascript function from HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, html-agility-pack

I want to use HtmlAgilityPack in a form application to read some pages content but on the page search subpage I need to invoke the javascript and the link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkbtnNext','')" id="lnkbtnNext">Następny >></a>
```

How can I Call this function from my C# desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust the source, it looks to me like you'd be better off invoking the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx). HtmlAgilityPack does not provide a scripting engine.