# Cannot Load the HTML through HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I try to parse HTML using HtmlAgilityPack using simple doc.load method by passing the URL, but it comes with the following result how can I resolve this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { 
  var exdate = new Date(); 
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays); 
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";
  expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/"; } 
  function getHostUri() 
  { var loc = document.location; return loc.toString(); }
  setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '202.142.170.42', 10); 
  setCookie('DOAReferrer', document.referrer, 10); location.href = getHostUri();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your   browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled.
>   Please change your   browser settings or upgrade your
>   browser.

This Message says it all, the side needs javascript to be loaded, and HtmlAgilityPack is no JavascriptEngine!

The Load Method of the HtmlDocument can not interpret and execute Javascript-Code it´s just a simple "Download"-Function for static HTML-Sites.

What you could try to do is, with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) (or [something else](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/?hl=de)) check which HttpRequest are made to get the content, and this Requests you have to [recreate in C#](http://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/simple-web-request-with-web-response/215) to get the HTML you want!

Here are some similar Questions:

[Running Scripts in HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack)

[C# - Get JavaScript variable value using HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315151/c-sharp-get-javascript-variable-value-using-htmlagilitypack)

[Calling javascript function from HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194715/calling-javascript-function-from-htmlagilitypack)